# Downloading an image from the Internet with specific DateTime in the URL

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, timezone, webclient

I am trying to develop an application that will fetch a file from a web server using a generated Url path.
A new file on the web server is created every second, and I am trying to access that file and display it in a PictureBox (old files are not deleted).
I have ran into some problems, the server is returning a `404` error, but I can't figure out why.
The application seems to be unable to download the file using the generated image source Url, but when I visit the generated link in a web browser (e.g Chrome, Internet Explorer), it works just fine.
I also ran into some problems along the way of having the URL not formatted correctly.

**Try 1:**
I tried to download the file using a string outputted by my URl generator. The URl must be in a date form: `yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss` in Tokyo Standard Time.  Generating this part worked fine and no problems arose. This is my code:

```
' Convert the time to Tokyo Standard Time
Dim japanTime = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time")) 

'Convert date to url that can be used in the Monitor url
Dim jTime_url As String = Convert.ToDateTime(japanTime.ToString()).ToString("yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss") 

'BYTE ARRAY HOLDS THE DATA
Try
    PictureBox1.Load("www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/" + jTime_url + ".jma_s.gif")
    Console.WriteLine("http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/" + jTime_url + ".jma_s.gif")
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The problem I ran into here was that I may have requested the latest file too quickly, so the web server would always report `"404 file not found"`.

**Try 2:** I tried delaying the file capture by 4 seconds. This worked, most of the time. The problems were that the file obtained from the web server only worked for most of the time due to that fact that once the "second" value reached `0`, the outputted string would be `-4` instead of `56`.
The second problem was that the entire code wouldn't work sometimes randomly, just returning the error `"404 file not found"`.
I tried outputting the Urls to the console and I viewed those online images in my web browser, and they worked just fine every time. The third problem was that I needed the "seconds" converted to be outputted as `00`, `01`, `02` etc.

```
Dim japanTime = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time")) 'Convert user computer time to TokyoTime (japan)

'For debugging purposes only (not enabled)
' MessageBox.Show(japanTime.ToString()) 

'FORMAT OUTPUTTED: 1/19/2020 1:47:18 PM

'Needed format: yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss
Dim oldsecond As String = Convert.ToDateTime(japanTime.ToString()).ToString("ss") 'Create the old second to make a delay (source code not right)
' Dim oldminute As String = Convert.ToDateTime(japanTime.ToString()).ToString("mm")

'The -1 Explains the code delay
Dim newsecond As String = oldsecond - 5 

Dim newnewsecond As String
If newsecond = -4 Then
    newnewsecond = "56"
Else
    If newsecond = -3 Then
        newnewsecond = "57"
    Else
        If newsecond = -2 Then
            newnewsecond = "58"
        Else
            If newsecond = -1 Then
                newnewsecond = "59"
            Else
                If newsecond = 0 Then
                    newnewsecond = "00"
                Else
                    newnewsecond = newsecond
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Label4.Text = newnewsecond

Dim jTime_url As String = Convert.ToDateTime(japanTime.ToString()).ToString("yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmm" & newnewsecond) 'Convert date to url that can be used in the Monitor url
Dim MyWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient

Try
    PictureBox1.Load("www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/" + jTime_url + ".jma_s.gif")
    Console.WriteLine("http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/" + jTime_url + ".jma_s.gif")
  Catch ex as Exception
    Console.Writeline(ex.message)
End Try
```

What I am trying to achieve here is that I want to be able to display this image source Url using the latest date information replacing  `yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss` and displaying it in a PictureBox.

Is there an error in my code, can I improvement it or do I have to re-write it in another way, shape, or form?

```
http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss.jma_s.gif
```

Sample url image source you can look at:
http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/20200304/20200304081359.jma_s.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the DateTime conversion method, using [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid), passing my [Local TimeZone.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local) and `"Tokyo Standard Time"` as parameters, to generate a [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) that represents the current Tokyo DateTime.

Using a Timer, subtracting 4 seconds from the calculated DateTimeOffset (**`DateTimeOffset.AddSeconds(-4)`**), the Images are loaded correctly.

► Note that the System clock must be synchronized with a [NTP Server](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome). `4` seconds is a relatively loose gap, but an unsynched clock will of course compromise the result anyway.

**EDIT**:
Changed **`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`** to **`System.Timers.Timer`**, since what takes more time here is the image download.
Using `BeginInvoke()` to set the `PictureBox.Image`, which takes almost nothing, prevents the UI from *stuttering* when the Form is moved around.

```
Private tokyoTimer As System.Timers.Timer = Nothing
Private tokyoClient As WebClient

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    tokyoTimer = New System.Timers.Timer() With {.Interval = 1000}
    tokyoClient = New WebClient()
    AddHandler tokyoTimer.Elapsed,
        Sub()
            Dim TokyoOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(Date.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Tokyo Standard Time")
            Dim currentImage As String = TokyoOffset.AddSeconds(-4).ToString("yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".jma_s.gif"
            Try
                Dim data = tokyoClient.DownloadData(New Uri($"http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/{currentImage}"))
                BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(
                    Sub()
                        PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
                        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(data))
                    End Sub))
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' The exception hadling can be quite extensive here, since many factor can cause it: 
                ' No server response, no Internet connection, internal server (500+) faults etc.
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
    tokyoTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    tokyoTimer.Enabled = False
    tokyoTimer.Dispose()
    tokyoClient?.Dispose()
End Sub
```

[image: Tokyo Images]

An asynchronous version of the same procedure, all contained in a class object.
The **`TokyoImagesDownloader`** class exposes two public methods:

▶ `StartDownload()` expects as arguments:

1. The PicureBox control used to show the downloaded images
2. The interval, in seconds, between downloads.
3. A delay value, in seconds, to subtract to the current Tokyo Local Time, to prevent the Server from returning `404 - Not found` because the requested image is not yet ready.

A `StopWatch` is used to synchronize the requested Interval between downloads, considering the time needed to download and show an image, so the clock shown in the Image itself should reflect the Interval requested.

▶ `StopDownload()` can be called at any time to stop the download of the images.

With:

```
StartDownload(PictureBox1, 1, 8)
```

the class is instructed to show the images in `PictureBox1`, download an image each second and delay the current Tokyo Time by 8 seconds.

```
Dim imageDonwloder As TokyoImagesDownloader = Nothing

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    imageDonwloder = New TokyoImagesDownloader()
    imageDonwloder.StartDownload(PictureBox1, 1, 8)
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    imageDonwloder.StopDownload()
End Sub
```

---

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class TokyoImagesDownloader

    Private tokyoClient As WebClient
    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing

    Public Sub StartDownload(canvas As PictureBox, intervalSeconds As Integer, serverTimeDelaySeconds As Integer)
        cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
        tokyoClient = New WebClient()
        Task.Run(Function() DownloadAsync(canvas, intervalSeconds, serverTimeDelaySeconds))
    End Sub

    Private Async Function DownloadAsync(canvas As PictureBox, intervalSeconds As Integer, serverTimeDelaySeconds As Integer) As Task
        Dim downloadTimeWatch As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
        downloadTimeWatch.Start()
        Do
            If cts.IsCancellationRequested Then Return
            Dim TokyoOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(Date.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Tokyo Standard Time")
            Dim currentImage As String = TokyoOffset.AddSeconds(-serverTimeDelaySeconds).ToString("yyyyMMdd/yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            Dim url = New Uri($"http://www.kmoni.bosai.go.jp/data/map_img/RealTimeImg/jma_s/{currentImage}.jma_s.gif")
            Try
                Dim data = Await tokyoClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url)
                canvas.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(
                    Sub()
                        canvas.Image?.Dispose()
                        canvas.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(data))
                    End Sub))
                Await Task.Delay((intervalSeconds * 1000) - CInt(downloadTimeWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds))
                downloadTimeWatch.Restart()
            Catch wEx As WebException
                Console.WriteLine(wEx.Message)
            End Try
        Loop
    End Function

    Public Sub StopDownload()
        cts.Cancel()
        tokyoClient?.CancelAsync()
        tokyoClient?.Dispose()
        cts?.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Jimi, thank you for solving the problem with the second count being (-4 etc, etc). The problem I have here is that I keep getting a error of 404 file not found (Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.). Please check out the code here: https://imgur.com/a/is6TBCJ

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure that you seen this link: https://imgur.com/a/is6TBCJ

Comment: Are you sure your clock is correctly set? Try to synch your machine time using the Internet Time panel. You can also try to remove more seconds (or an hour). Btw, if I subtract 4 hours, the server answers `404` to me too. But not always!

Comment: thanks! I synchronized with the NIST internet time instead of WINDOWS internet time and It works fine! Thank you for your helo

Comment: Sometimes after a few minutes, I get the error: System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'. I think everything in your code looks fine; but how do I get rid of that

Comment: If you can't get the error to appear, here is mine: https://imgur.com/a/wSdS79W

Comment: What Framework version are you using? It's the PictureBox that throws (you could Catch Exception and let it go, to see what happens). I started it at 10:42 Tokyo time and it's still going. Anyway, I'll change the code to use WebClient instead.

Comment: I'm using .NET framework 4.7.2 with Visual Basic Forms Project, could you please add another section of WebClient based code with the original code?

Comment: I've changed the code again. Note that I'm using a different Timer now. I'll update it again (see the note) when I have some spare time.

Comment: The different timer seems to be working absolutely fine. I didn't get any parameter errors as I did with the first snippet you sent me. Thanks you so much.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but I still am encountering a problem. After running for a few minutes, another 'parameter not valid' error displays. Is there a way I can eliminate that? New error: https://imgur.com/a/LYFzVFS

Comment: An error while receiving bytes from the web can always occur. There's a Catch block for that. Since receiving erroneous bytes can also generate general exceptions, add `Catch ex As Exception` after the existing `Catch` block and use it for logging purposes, if necessary, or leave it blank to just ignore it (an empty catch block is sometimes required).

Comment: I just remembered that, by mistake, I left the application running for hours and it didn't stop. I'll try again, letting it run for the night. But, there's not guarantee that the server will always return correct data. It may just return an internal error. This happens frequently (or, more frequently that you may expect).

Comment: The server has never returned an internal error for me. It always just says "Parameter Not Found". Also, I tried using the exact code you gave me, but it still crashes the application (the 'Catch' doesn't work)

Comment: I put it under test. It has been running for 6 hours now. No exceptions (this is logged, so I know). There's one thing that can make it error out (well, this is not production code): the StopWatch, if something make the procedure change pace, could get in the way. Try removing it, changing `Await Task.Delay((intervalSeconds * 1000) - CInt(downloadTimeWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds))` in just `Await Task.Delay(intervalSeconds * 1000)`. It'll be less *precise*, but safer. I'll give it a twist as soon as I can.

Comment: I stopped it now. 12 hours running, not a single exception. My guess is that the StopWatch is the cause of the (recoverable) exception, probably because your network connection is not performant enough to keep up with the 1sec interval, thus subtracting the time needed to download the Image from the base interval, causes the interval value to go below `0`, which generates a recoverable exception (since if you set a negative value, the default is used instead). This, however, can cause the exception to persist in the next iteration, because the StopWatch is not reset. I'll see to fix it.

Comment: What I decided to do was to log unhanded exceptions instead of crashing the application. I added some code in `ApplicationEvents.vb` so that the application would continue instead of stopping with the "Parameter is Invalid" error, because the program could still continue as normal even with the error.

Comment: You should monitor/log the time needed to complete the request, so you can fine-tune the delay. If you remove the StopWatch as suggested, you won't get exceptions but you should verify how much time the request actually takes to complete.