# VB: Convert time as string into current time zone

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timezone

I have a time string of for example `18:30:00` and know that it will always be a time in Japan, I would like to have this time converted to my own time zone (but not specifically mine).

I've had a go at this but it just isn't working. How do I do this?

I've tried the following:

```
Dim LocalZone As TimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
Dim SystemTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(CStr(LocalZone.StandardName))
Dim JapaneseTime As DateTimeOffset = "Insert String with H:M:S format here"
Dim localTime As DateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(JapaneseTime, SystemTimeZone)
Dim TimeHere As String = localTime.ToString
TimeHere = Left(localTime.DateTime, (localTime.DateTime).ToString.IndexOf("M") + 1) 'snipping just the time
Console.Writeline(TimeHere)
```

An `JapaneseTime` input of "17:59:00" outputs "05:59:00 PM" which doesn't do any convert between the time zones at all, just 12-24 hour times.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9B81.png) is the variable watch window.

Comment: First paragraph here: [Downloading an image from the Internet with specific DateTime in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60517517/7444103)

Comment: To local TimeZone: `dim localTimeFromJPTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Parse("17:59:00"), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time"), TimeZoneInfo.Local)`. Inverse: `dim jpOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(localTimeFromJPTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Tokyo Standard Time")`. -- Don't parse pieces out of DateTime objects converted to strings, you have `.TimeOfDay` for that, if you just need the time part of a DateTime.

Comment: @Jimi - please post as an answer, not a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hou0bou - Don't use the `TimeZone` class.  Always use `TimeZoneInfo` instead.  Also, one can't actually do this conversion without specifying or implying a date as well as a time.  The result can vary significantly depending on which date you are talking about.  If you don't specify a date, parsing a time will imply "today", but then you will get a different result depending on when you execute your code.